# Android Studio Build Error : This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run

Tags: android-studio, gradle, version

I upgraded Android Studio version from 1.5 to 2.0 today and something has gone wrong.
First I got Gradle version error, so I updated Gradle version from 2.10 to 2.12.

```
# previous
# distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
# current
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.12-all.zip
```

Gradle version error has disappeared.
But now I have this error when I try to run my project:

```
Error running app: This version of Android Studio is incompatible with the Gradle Plugin used. Try disabling Instant Run (or updating either the IDE or the Gradle plugin to the latest version)
```

This is my Project Gradle.build:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is my module:app Gradle.build file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount = 4 // this is the default value
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') { transitive = true; }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.12.1@aar') { transitive = true; }

    apt 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher-processor:2.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:2.1.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I disabled Instant Run from Preferences but nothing changed.
How can I resolve this error?
I'm struggling for half days.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I deleted the build folder after cleaning project, and everything is just working fine now. :D
I don't know exactly why this happen, but maybe pre-built setting conflicted with new build setting.

Comment: I deleted the build folder and cleaned the project  but still same error is dispalyed

Comment: For Gradle 2.0 + follow the @Tran Duc Huy.Worked for me

Answer (score 10):

I faced this issue after updating Android Studio to 2.3!
I didn't delete any file!

**Just cleaned the project** and it worked!

Answer (score 8):

On Android 2.0 and above.

1 - In `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` option -> `Instant Run`

2 - Clear `Enable instant run to hot swap code`

3 - Clean project

p/s : It should totally work.

Comment: Disabling Instant Run is not a *fix*.

Comment: As for someone, "For Gradle 2.0 + follow the @Tran Duc Huy.Worked for me"

Answer (score 4):

I'm Using Android Studio 2.2, and for me...
Clean the project and delete build folder solved the issue.

I have just one different with you. I putted on build.gradle.
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that Android Studio up to date!!

**AndroidStudio** > **Help** > **Check For Updates ...**

Answer (score 1):

```
Plugin version  Required Gradle version


1.0.0 - 1.1.3   2.2.1 - 2.3

1.2.0 - 1.3.1   2.2.1 - 2.9

1.5.0   2.2.1 - 2.13

2.0.0 - 2.1.2   2.10 - 2.13

2.1.3 - 2.2.3   2.14.1+

2.3.0+  3.3+
```

e.g.  set the Gradle version to 3.3 in the gradle-wrapper.properties file.

```
...
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
...
```

set the Android plugin for Gradle to version 2.3.0 from the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
  }
}
```

Also you have to make sure there are no clashes by checking:
`File` - > `Project Structure` - > (click on)`Project`

Answer (score 0):

1. go to Preferences and find Gradle
2. select "Use default Gradle wrapper"
3. Build - Clean Project

and it will update the Gradle file for you automatically and run in a while.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the project (Build -> Clean Project) is the right thing to do in this case.